# Can I go to the USA With a Polish passport

Tags: visas, usa, polish-citizens

I was born in Poland and lived in the UK. I'm in the EU settlement scheme but I got a Polish passport. How can I travel to the USA?

Answer (score 8):

You absolutely can go to the US with a Polish passport. The best way would be air travel.

For visits for less than 90 days for tourism or business purposes, you can use the [Visa Waiver Program (VWP)](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visa-waiver-program.html). For other visits or longer duration of the visit you'll need to apply for a visa.

Comment: Im wanting to meet a friend i live in UK tho with a polish passport and are in the eu settlement scheme does this change anything

Comment: @BassBeats meeting a friend is called "tourism", and as long as you can show that you don't have an intent to overstay your visa the US doesn't really care how you acquired your legal status in the UK.

Comment: @BassBeats Indeed, the US doesn't much care _whether_ you have legal status in the UK.

Comment: So as long as i got a polish passport and apply for that visa waiver i can travel to the us?

Comment: @BassBeats the waiver has to be granted before you will be able to go; sometimes they are refused.  If it is refused you'll need to apply for a visa instead. The waiver will normally be granted unless you fail the background check (which can sometimes be the result of mistaken identity) or if you're ineligible (the application has several questions to determine whether you're eligible -- grounds for ineligibility include the commission of certain crimes, travel to certain countries, and 
past violation of the terms of the visa waiver program).

Comment: Never travelled out the country before does disabilities like ADHD/Autism have an influence?

Comment: @BassBeats no. If you need medications - make sure to have prescription for everything, carry in original packaging, and take only what's needed for the duration of your trip (and some extra for unexpected delays and emergencies, but not something that may appear as trafficking).

Comment: @BassBeats nope, all you need is a valid ESTA approval, and (if applicable) a certified list of prescription medication you take (your pharmacy should be able to provide that for free or at a nominal fee). The latter may not even be needed depending on the medication, but better safe than sorry. And as said, always carry any medication in its original packaging.

Comment: @littleadv You _should_ double-check all your prescriptions are legal in your destination country; a friend of mine got into quite a headache bringing his prescription to the US when it turned out that particular drug wasn’t legal in the US (some high-power sleep aid IIRC).

Comment: @BassBeats It’s already been mentioned, but do make sure and cross-check the medications against the current [US Controlled Substance lists](https://www.deadiversion.usdoj.gov/schedules/) (and make sure and check by scientific name, _not_ drug name, drug names are branding). I know from experience that at least some ADHD medications fall under Schedule II. IANAL, so I can’t tell you what you would need to do if any of your medications _are_ on the list, but it’s better to know (and be able to research what you need to do about it) ahead of time than to have to deal with it when you show up.

Comment: The med is xaggitin 54mg methylphenidate hydrochloride 54mg so not sure